# How to implement << and >> for pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to get '<<' and '>>' to work for pointers as I have coded below for my driver in main.

```
int main()
{
using namespace std;


cout << "Welcome to My TrashCan Program!" << endl;

TrashCan myCan;
TrashCan yourCan;
TrashCan empty( 0, 0 );
TrashCan * ptrCan = new TrashCan( 0, 0 );
TrashCan * nullCan = NULL; // pointer to null

// using pointers here
cin >> ptrCan;
cin >> nullCan;  // 

cout << ptrCan << endl;
cout << nullCan << endl;  //
return 0;}
```

Im assuming I would have to implement these functions somewhere, but am not quite sure how:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const TrashCan * drive );
friend std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, TrashCan * & drive );
```

Comment: You're not technically allowed to do this.

Comment: What exactly are we typing in that gets loaded into the pointer. The address?

Answer (score 5):

Reading a pointer from `cin` will almost never work. That's why the language doesn't let you by default. A line like:

```
cin >> ptrCan;
```

would lose track of (i.e. leak) the object you got from `new TrashCan( 0, 0 );` a few lines earlier, if it were allowed.

Please explain what you're really trying to do.